# Reports endpoint returns System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed

Tags: powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the Usage (report) data from Microsoft Graph using PowerShell but I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: 
An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
   ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

It looks like server is terminating the connection abruptly.

Here are the commands that I am using through PowerShell

```bsh
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$headers = @{Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $AT.AccessToken; ContentType='application/json'}
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')?$format=text/csv" -Headers $headers
```

This is happening intermittently, regardless of setting `Tls12`. I have analyzed the packets through Wireshark and it looks like TLS handshake was completed correctly.

```
Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
```

I also see that Change Cipher Spec was communicated by client and server.

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Change Cipher Spec Protocol: Change Cipher Spec
```

It is important to note that I am able to get the `Users` and `SubscribedSkus` correctly, so I can't conclude that this is happening because of the TLS issues. It's only the `/reports` endpoint which is causing the problem.

Any insight will be helpful to address this problem.
Is it possible that Usage data is large and leads to connection termination?

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint doesn't return the data directly, it returns a 302 redirect to a CSV file to download. You'll want to sepcifiy an `OutFile` to save the file to:

```bsh
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')?$format=text/csv"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -OutFile report.csv
```